# How to find out which collection a token mint belongs to

Tags: spl-token, web3.js, nft, spl-token-program, nfts

I have Update Authority Address and Verified Creator Address of Collection X.

I have mint address and metadata address of a token, now I want to check out if this token belongs to the collection X. (Without sending any additional request to any endpoint.)

Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that without doing an additional request, unless you have stored that information somewhere.

However, it isn't that hard, if you have the metadata address you can use
`@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` and do a `Metadata.fromAccountAddress` call, then validate that the creator set matches the expected verified creators.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections

Comment: Unfortunately, I am scanning transactions (subscribing to Magic Eden Listing Program), and almost 10 transactions are being sent in a sec, so there is no time to send a separate request for each of them to get the metadata. 
Somehow I have to verify a newly listed item belongs to collection X.
I have updateAuthority, and verifiedCreatorAddress of collection X and 
I have tokenMintAddress and metadataAddress of a newly listed token...